# how to add color to error message in yup schema object in reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, react-native, yup

I am using yup schema object for field validation in react.
so anyone know how to add color to error message or any other way to add color to requird message

below is the code -

```
     const ValidationSchema = yup.object({name: yup
.string('Enter your name'),
age:yup
.number('Enter your name'),
.required('number required')
})
```

This is how the form is being used -

```
 const formik = useFormik({
    initialValues: {
        name: '',
        customerId:'',
        email:'',
        phoneNumber:'',
        age: '',
        gender: '',
        race: '',
        state_code: '',
        county_code: '',
    },
    validationSchema: validationSchema,
    onSubmit: async (values) => {
        let diseases = Object.keys(selectValue).filter((keyName) => selectValue[keyName] === true && keyName)
     console.log(responseAPI)
    },
});

  <form onSubmit={formik.handleSubmit}>
                                <Grid container rowSpacing={2} columnSpacing={{ xs: 1, sm: 2, md: 3 }} sx={{ marginBottom: '2em' }}>
                                    <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={4} sx={{ fontWeight: 'initial', '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '25ch' }, }}>
                                        <ArgonTextField
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange} value={formik.values.name} id="name" type="string" name="name"
                                            placeholder="Name"
                                        />
                                    </Grid>
                                  
                                
                                    <Grid item xs={12} md={6} lg={4} sx={{ fontWeight: 'initial', '& .MuiTextField-root': { m: 1, width: '25ch' }, }}>
                                        <ArgonTextField placeholder="Phone Number"
                                            onChange={formik.handleChange} value={formik.values.phoneNumber} id="phoneNumber" type="number" name="phoneNumber"
                                        />
                                    </Grid>
                                   
                            
                                </Grid>
                                <AddCustomerDetails data={values} selectValue={selectValue} setSelectValue={setSelectValue} diseases={diseases} formik={formik} setDiseases={setDiseases}
                                    description={description} setDescription={setDescription}
                                />
                            </form>
```

so I want number required message color to be red its now black in color.

Comment: What are you using for the form? You are not setting color in yup.

Comment: @AlijaFajić I have edited the question ! I am very new to ReactJs